# Strange automation? error in Word2007

Tags: vba, automation, ms-office, office-2007, ms-word

I'm pulling my hair out because I've run into the following problem with one of my clients:

My program uses extensive VBA automation in Word. Macros are saved in a specific Word template that is attached to each document. Some of the macros save the current document to a temporary folder under [User]/AppData/Roaming/... for further processing.

The client is using Win7 with Office2007 (Student edition). On the computer in question I keep getting an error with something like "No permission to save the file" (can't give exact error message because I've translated it from my language to English)

This happens when the macro tries to "SaveAs" the document.

The strange thing is that it happens only 8 out of 10 times - and not all the time. There are no special permissions set for the temporary folder I'm trying to save to.

I've tried changing Word security settings, tried adding the folder to the trusted folders list, tried using a different folder - to no avail.

The client's computer has Norton Antivirus (or Internet Security, I dunno) installed but temporary disabling it didn't solve the problem. (I know I should only be sure after a full uninstall but I can't do that on the client's comp)

Any help is appreciated!

---

**Update:** I've since found the exact error message in English: "Word cannot complete the save due to a file permission error."

I'm now looking on the web for similar forum posts but if you guys know something, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: So the SaveAs command works correctly 100% of the time on computers other than the one in question? (In other words, you're sure it's just one computer that experiences the problem?)

Comment: Yes, it works 100% of the time on every computer I've tested up to now. Except the one mentioned above.

Comment: Have you checked for viruses and run a repair of Word / Office on the problem computer?

Comment: No. But today I've run into the same problem on another computer. It seems they are both running Windows7 with Office2007 and both are recent installs. I've tested my program thoroughly a few months ago under Win7/Office2007 but there were no issues. Maybe a security update has been issued since then, which is breaking my code?

Comment: Silly question (sometimes happens): is a file you use or you overwrite already open ?

Comment: I'm trying to SaveAs the document currently open in Word - works without problems on every other computer. I believe this must be either a) Microsoft Security Update b) some other unknown issue

Comment: I realize this may be a pain, but have you tried changing the code on the effected computers so the file is saved to a different directory, such as the user's documents folder? Same results?

Comment: The temporary directory can be set in my application and I've tried setting it to a different one (not the documents folder though). Same results...

Comment: One more thought: In the newest version of my program, I'm monitoring temporary directories using ReadDirectoryChangesW. Maybe this is causing the problem? What I find strange is that I've just tested the new version in a Win7/Word2007 virtual PC and found no errors. So once more, this doesn't explain anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is an antivirus or similar program running?  On my development computers many similar problems went away when I changed from (vendor "X" security bundle) to [ESET](http://markjerde.blogspot.com/2010/11/eset-smart-security.html).

Comment: Hello! Client's computer has Norton Antivirus installed. I tried disabling it, but it didn't help. Do you think there is a chance that uninstalling it might solve the issue?

Comment: You were right on. Norton AV was causing the problem. Turning it off didn't help, removing it entirely did. I'm also a fan of ESET, it just works.